# Find python files that start with same string in a list of file paths

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

```
[' D:\\2019-09-06_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_06627_012_20190906T075008_0601_02_ETinst.tif', ' D:\\2019-09-06_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_06627_012_20190906T075008_0601_02_ETinstUncertainty.tif', ' D:\\2019-09-06_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_06627_013_20190906T075100_0601_01_ETinst.tif', ' D:\\2019-09-06_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_06627_013_20190906T075100_0601_01_ETinstUncertainty.tif', ' D:\\2019-09-14_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_06749_010_20190914T043343_0601_02_ETinst.tif', ' D:\\2019-09-14_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_06749_010_20190914T043343_0601_02_ETinstUncertainty.tif', ' D:\\2019-10-29_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_07451_013_20191029T104129_0601_01_ETinst.tif', ' D:\\2019-10-29_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_07451_013_20191029T104129_0601_01_ETinstUncertainty.tif', ' D:\\2019-11-13_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_07680_016_20191113T050013_0601_01_ETinst.tif', ' D:\\2019-11-13_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_07680_016_20191113T050013_0601_01_ETinstUncertainty.tif', ' D:\\2019-11-13_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_07680_017_20191113T050105_0601_01_ETinst.tif', ' D:\\2019-11-13_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_07680_017_20191113T050105_0601_01_ETinstUncertainty.tif', ' D:\\2019-12-17_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_08207_001_20191217T034051_0601_01_ETinst.tif', ' D:\\2019-12-17_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_08207_001_20191217T034051_0601_01_ETinstUncertainty.tif']
```

I have a list of file paths in a python list. I want to find all files which belong to the same date e.g.4 files have names beginning with `'2019-09-06'`. How can I divide this list into smaller lists each of which has files with the same date in the beginning? I do not know the common dates so the solution should be able to find them dynamically.

Comment: `str.split()` along with indexing might help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use dictionary to store the files with same date and date as the key.

```
from collections import defaultdict
dates=defaultdict(list)
for path in paths:
    key,val=path[4:14],path[14:]
    dates[key].append(val)
```

Comment: thanks! I get this error `*** TypeError: first argument must be callable or None` in `dates=defaultdict(list)`

Comment: You have to pass `list` function to `defaultdict`. May be you overrided `list` by naming a variable *list*.

Comment: Not a problem. Always happy to help. Mind upvoting? @user308827

Comment: Much appreciated @user308827

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
paths = [' D:\\2019-09-06_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_06627_012_20190906T075008_0601_02_ETinst.tif', ' D:\\2019-09-06_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_06627_012_20190906T075008_0601_02_ETinstUncertainty.tif', ' D:\\2019-09-06_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_06627_013_20190906T075100_0601_01_ETinst.tif', ' D:\\2019-09-06_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_06627_013_20190906T075100_0601_01_ETinstUncertainty.tif', ' D:\\2019-09-14_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_06749_010_20190914T043343_0601_02_ETinst.tif', ' D:\\2019-09-14_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_06749_010_20190914T043343_0601_02_ETinstUncertainty.tif', ' D:\\2019-10-29_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_07451_013_20191029T104129_0601_01_ETinst.tif', ' D:\\2019-10-29_ECOSTRESS_L3_ET_PT-JPL_07451_013_20191029T104129_0601_01_ETinstUncertainty.tif']
arrays=[]
dates = input().split(" ")
#input dates
for  path in paths :
      array = []
      for date in dates:                
            match = re.search(date,path)
            if match is not None:
                   array.append(path)
      arrays.append(array)
```

i used regular expression to sort this.You can input your values into the dates array if you would like to but .This gives you a list of sorted lists.

Comment: thanks @Angry_Cder, however, the solution cannot hard code '2019-09-06' as the actual list is much longer